# Stacking Images When Page Loads

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've read through a number of similar questions but nothing has worked for me yet.  The url is here:  http://www.promotion1.com/home-wmc-slide

I've installed a slider and the images are stacking before the script, I do not know JavaScript...

Would anyone be willing to look at the site and see if there might be a quick fix?  I seriously need the help.

Thank you!

Comment: Just a pointer, but if you're talking about a jQuery plugin you're using ***JavaScript***, not ***Java***.

Comment: Thank you, I am new at this and I appreciate the tip.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your javascript from $(window).load(...) to $(document).ready(..)

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("#pikame").PikaChoose();
});
```

Comment: Here is a link that gives a brief explanation between using document ready and window load.
http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/documentready-vs-windowload/.

Hope that helps give some context.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the suggestion.  I started with $(document).ready(..) and had the same issue.  After reading through a number of posts, I recently changed it to .load().

Comment: How about just hiding the block in the css initially `#pickame { display: none; }` then in the code above, change it to `$("#pickame").PikaChoose().show();`

Comment: Thank you also for the explanation link, good info!  I just changed it back to the .ready if you wish to see that there is no change.  The page is loaded with SEO and other codes, I was thinking maybe that was the issue for the load time.

Comment: I tried the { display: none } but I might not be placing it properly.  The images were hidden and only the thumbs were visible.

Comment: Hey! I found the spot!  Thank you so much for the info!

Comment: Cool! I was going to say, I just looked and it seemed to work :)

Comment: Hey, could you possibly help with one other thing? lol I want the slider to continue to cycle after clicking a thumbnail.  The slider stops after clicking it and it's driving me crazy!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the newest version of PikaChoose and then do the following.
For your css:
`#pikame{ display:none; }`

In your js:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var showUL = function(){ $("#pikame").show(); };
    $("#pikame").PikaChoose({buildFinished:showUL});
});
```